# VBA Variable Workbook Reference Runtime-Error 9

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a VlookUp with two seperate workbooks. The main workbook opens the supporting workbook right at the beginning like this:

```
Public Sub GetFile()

Dim MySourceSheet As Variant, wb As Workbook

'Opens window to choose file from
MySourceSheet = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
    "Excel Files (*.XLS; *.XLSX), *.XLS; *.XLSX", Title:="Select file to 
    retrieve data from.")
If MySourceSheet = False Then Exit Sub                       
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MySourceSheet)                       

End Sub
```

Throughout the module I reference the document a few times, and then there is this part were the error occurs.

```
 Private Sub VlookupToBeReviewed()

Dim LastColumn As Long

Workbooks("09_PR Status Custodians.xlsm").Activate                                           'change name
'inserts new column
With Sheets("Prio_Custodians")
    LastColumn = Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                       'change row! 'defines last column
    For i = LastColumn To LastColumn Step -2                                         'moves two columns to the left
        .Columns(i).Insert
        .Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 10
    Next
End With

'puts in the date
Cells(3, LastColumn).Value = Date

'sets up the variables for the vlookup
Dim rw As Long, col As Range
Dim twb As Workbook

'sets up the workbooks
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set col = Workbooks(MySourceSheet).Sheets("Documents to be reviewed").Range("A:B")

'vlookup function
With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, LastColumn) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, col, 2, False)
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

Error:

```
Set col = Workbooks(MySourceSheet).Sheets("Documents to be reviewed").Range("A:B")
```

Spits out the

> Run-time error '9' (Subscript out of range)

However, when I move my courser over `MySourceSheet` it shows the correct workbook as defined earlier in the module. If I put the name of the workbook manually with the .xls extension, it works all perfectly fine.I tried looking for an answer all over the web but nothing could quite fix it. I'd very much appreciate some help! :)

Comment: Can you share the output for the `MySourceSheet` from the Immediate Window in the debug mode. Thanks

Comment: why not use `wb.sheets(....` as you defined the sheet to be `wb.`

Comment: If you have already opened the workbook using the variable `wb`, you can simply use `Set col = wb.Sheets("Documents to be reviewed").Range("A:B")` Of course, you'll have to make sure to retain the variable throughout your program ...

Comment: If you have declared `MySourceSheet` in one procedure it won't be available in another.

Comment: You should make `wb` a module level variable and use that. Even if it had the value from earlier as you say (which isn't possible from the code you posted), `mysourcesheet` would include a path and therefore be of no use.

Comment: Thank you all. I thought that's what I did, Rory. I declared it right at the beginning of the code. I didn't post the entire code, but that's what it showed in the Watcher as well. I'm really new to this, and doing my best to learn. I deleted all the other Subs, so that I would only have one Sub Sub End in the code. That did it. It now works perfectly, though I'll have to figure out how to use the Sub function better... Thanks again!